# Is there a more efficient way to use StringReplace?

Tags: export, import, string-manipulation

I have constructed a table that I want to save in such a way that it looks like a python input because of reasons. For that I save the table's output in a .txt file and then perform a [StringReplace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) over said .txt file. However, as one can see, this is quite unefficient and ugly. I have to produce twice the number of files. Is there a way to call directly to savedX from `StringReplace`

```
Export["savedWindX.txt", savedX]

savedXPython = 
  Import["savedWindX.txt"] // 
    StringReplace[
      #, 
      {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", "t" -> "m.lammda1[i] *180/np.pi", 
       "u" -> "m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi"}] &
```

Comment: Why not use `ExportString[]` first, do your replacements on it, and then finally use `Export[]` on the processed string?

Comment: `savedXText = ExportString[savedX, "Text"]` seems to work fine. however, if I then write `savedXPython = 
 StringReplace[
   savedXText, {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", 
    "t" -> "m.lammda1[i]*180/np.pi", "u" -> "m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi"}] &`, the output doesn't look like the one that I obtain in the question; the output is `StringReplace[
  savedXText, {"[" -> "(", "]" -> ")", 
   "t" -> "m.lammda1[i]*180/np.pi", "u" -> "m.phi1[i]*180/np.pi"}] &`

Comment: @slow_learner Just remove the `&` at the end.